# SwifterでユーザをAuthorizeできない

Tags: swift, oauth

teratailでも質問した内容ですが、こちらでも質問させていただきます。

アプリ内でツイート、ダイレクトメッセージの送信、タイムラインの取得を行うOSアプリケーションを開発しています。その際、ユーザを[Swifter](https://github.com/mattdonnelly/Swifter)でOAuthを介してauthorizeする際に、SFSafatiViewController内でtwitter認証したのち、画面が閉じた途端にエラーが出てしまい認証ができません。

エラーメッセージと該当箇所のコードおよびライブラリなどのバージョンは以下の通りです。
`LogInTwitterViewController.swift`内の`LogInTwitter()`中の`authorize()`を除いてtwitter developerから取得したアクセストークンを用いたところ、テストツイートは作動したため(ただし認証画面は表示されずデベロッパ登録したアカウントからツイートされる)、おそらく`authorize( )`の使い方に何かしら問題があるのではないかと思っています。
iOS開発は初心者なので破茶滅茶な質問をしているかもしれませんが、ご寛恕願います。

**エラーメッセージ** ("Failed In Logging In"はエラー箇所の特定のため表示させています)

```
Failed In Logging In
SwifterError(message: "Bad OAuth response received from server", kind: badOAuthResponse)
```

**Swifter関連箇所のソースコード**

LoggingInTwitter.swift

```swift
import Foundation
import SwifteriOS

public var isLoggedInTwitter = false

public let swifter = Swifter(consumerKey: "コンシューマキー", consumerSecret: "コンシューマシークレット")
```

LogInTwitterViewController.swift

```swift
import UIKit
import SafariServices
import SwifteriOS

class LoggingInTwitterViewController: UIViewController, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        if(isLoggedInTwitter){
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueFromStartingViewToHomeView", sender: nil)
        }
        else{
          self.LogInTwitter()
        }
    }

func LogInTwitter(){
        swifter.authorize(
            withCallback: URL(string:"app-アプリ名://")!,
            presentingFrom: self,
            success: { accessToken, response in
                guard let accessToken = accessToken else {
                    return
                }
                let oAuthToken = accessToken.key
                let secret = accessToken.secret
                UserDefaults.standard.set(oAuthToken, forKey: "oAuthToken")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(secret, forKey: "secret")
　　　　　　　　　 isLoggedInTwitter = true
        }, failure: { error in
            print("Failed In Logging In")
            print(error)
        })
        guard let oAuthToken = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "oAuthToken") else { return }
        guard let secret = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "secret") else { return }

        //認証情報の格納
        let Sw_Token = Credential.OAuthAccessToken(key: oAuthToken, secret: secret)
        let Sw_credential = Credential(accessToken: Sw_Token)
        swifter.client.credential = Sw_credential
　　　　　//テストツイート
        swifter.postTweet(status: "This is test tweet")

　　　　 //
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueFromStartingViewToHomeView", sender: nil)
    }
```

AppDelegate.swift

```swift
import UIKit
import CoreData
import SwifteriOS
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        Swifter.handleOpenURL(URL(string:"app-アプリ名://")!)
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        self.saveContext()
    }

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "アプリ名")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**実行環境**
Xcode 10.3
Swift 5
Swifter-2.2.2
CocoaPod 1.7.5

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/204590

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swiftの文法は全く知りませんが、GitHubの多くの人の実装を見ると、

```swift
withCallback: URL(string:"app-アプリ名://")!,
```

ではなく、次のようにしていますね。

```swift
withCallback: URL(string: "アプリ名://success")!,
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！試してみます！

Comment: [マルチポスト先](https://teratail.com/questions/204590)も参照した上で、ご指摘通り`withCallback:`に設定するURLをTwitter Developer Platformや`info.plist`上で設定したカスタムURLの後に"success"を付随させたものにしたところ正常に動作しました。ありがとうございました。